# How to document variable number of parameters in certain situations with JSDoc

Tags: javascript, jsdoc

I have something like this where my function only takes in the second and third parameters when the first one is `!= 3`. How can I document this behaviour with JSDoc?

```
getTimeframe: function(timeframe, since, until) {
/*
 * @param {Number} timeframe Can be 0, 1, 2 or 3
 * @param {Number} since Optional when timeframe !== 3
 * @param {Number} until Optional when timeframe !== 3
 */
...

}
```

Comment: What version of jsdoc are you using?

Comment: Use square brackets for optional parameters.

Comment: @Louis I'm using JSDoc 3, not generating any docs ATM, only trying to better understand it

Comment: @torazaburo I know about square brackets, what I'm trying to determine is what the correct syntax is when some params are optional in certain cases ONLY, and not always optional.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know the following is the best you can currently do with jsdoc 3. The key is to use `@also` to indicate that the function has more than one signature. Then you have spell out in your description when one signature applies and when the other applies, etc.

```
/**
 * When the <code>timeframe</code> parameter is not 3...
 *
 * @param {number} timeframe Can be 0, 1, 2.
 * @param {number} [since] blah.
 * @param {number} [until] blah.
 *
 * @also
 *
 * When the <code>timeframe</code> is 3, then...
 *
 * @param {number} timeframe Set to 3.
 */
function getTimeframe(timeframe, since, until) {

}
```

This will create two signatures for the `getTimeframe` function.

(Note: I prefer using `number` and not `Number` in a case like above because `1 instanceof Number` (for instance) is `false`. On the other hand `typeof 1` is `"number"` and `typeof Number(1)` is also `"number"`.)